# Reference One Open-Response String

Tags: c#

I'm currently trying to manipulate a sort of room system using switches. Now how I would love to do this is referencing one string that will always output into the same value. For example:

```
int roomIs = 0;

Console.WriteLine("Hello World. Type /Help for help or /Play to play!");
roomIs = 1;
string Enter = Console.ReadLine();

switch (Enter)
{
   case ("/Help"):
   Console.Clear();
   Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the help room, type /Return to return to your last room!");
   break;

   case ("/Return"):
    if (roomIs == 1){
     Console.Clear();
     Console.WriteLine("Hello World. Type /Help for help or /Play to play!")
    }
   break;
}
```

How can I reference the string `Enter` multiple times under the same name? So I can simply test what input I get, instead of having to create a new string every time I want to add in new options. (In the code I wish to reference the string Enter again when doing the `/Return` command, that is where I need help.)

I've tried looking through the StringBuilder function, yet I can't seem to make it apply to this.

Comment: If you want to re-use `Enter` for new input, just say `Enter = Console.ReadLine();` - i.e. leave the `string` off the front.

Comment: However, it looks like you want some kind of loop around this code, in which case, the initial `ReadLine` could simply be inside it at the top, and you wouldn't have to repeat yourself in every `case`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your're wanting:

```
        int roomIs = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Hello World. Type /Help for help or /Play to play!");
        roomIs = 1;
        var Enter = default(string);
        do
        {
            Enter = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (Enter)
            {
                case ("/Help"):
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the help room, type /Return to return to your last room!");
                    break;

                case ("/Return"):
                    if (roomIs == 1)
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("Hello World. Type /Help for help or /Play to play!");
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Enter));
```

is that correct?